# Binding JQ grid with XML response coming from VB6 dll

Tags: xml, asp-classic, jqgrid, vb6

I want to bind the JQgrid (in a Classic ASP page) with XML response I am getting from a VB6 COM .dll. All attempts to do so has failed so far unfortunately. I'd highly appreciate any help on this matter. Here is the that I have in my classic ASP page. All of the code is in one single .ASP file.

```js
$(function () {
    jQuery("#grid_top").jqGrid({
        datatype: 'xmlstring',
        datastr: strResponse, // 
        pager: '#pager',
        height: 250,
        colNames:['Order ID','Segment', 'Terminal','Product','Delivered','Customer','Gross','Manifest ID','Notes'],
        colModel:[
            {name:'OrderID',index:'orderId', width:100, xmlmap: function (obj) {
                    return $(obj).attr('OrderId');}},
            {name:'Segment',index:'segment', width:60, xmlmap: function (obj) {
                    return $(obj).attr('RouteSegment');}},
            {name:'Terminal',index:'terminal', width:100, xmlmap: function (obj) {
                    return $(obj).attr('TerminalId');}},
            {name:'Product',index:'product', width:80, align:"right",xmlmap:  function (obj) {
                    return $(obj).attr('ProductId');}},
            {name:'Delivered',index:'delivered', width:100, align:"right", xmlmap: function (obj) {
                    return $(obj).attr('DeliveredTimestamp');}},        
            {name:'Customer',index:'customer', width:150,align:"right", xmlmap: function (obj) {
                    return $(obj).attr('Customer');}},
            {name:'Gross',index:'gross', width:100, xmlmap: function (obj) {
                    return $(obj).attr('Gross');}},
            {name:'Manifest ID',index:'gross', width:100, 
                        xmlmap: function (obj) {
                     return $(obj).attr('ManifestId');}},   
            {name:'Notes',index:'note', width:150, sortable:false}      
        ],
        xmlReader: { root: "Data", row: "Row", repeatitems: false },
        multiselect: true,
        caption: "Deliver Orders for Route:"
    });
});
```

### Here is the code which is calling COM method

```vb
<%
Dim strRequest :strRequest = "<?xml version= ""1.0"" encoding= ""iso-8859-1"" ?>"
strRequest = strRequest & " METHOD='FetchOrder'/>"

objMSXML1.async = False
objMSXML1.validateOnParse = True
objMSXML1.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
objMSXML1.loadXML strRequest

strResponse = objManifest1.XMLDriver(CStr(strConnectionString1), objMSXML1.xml)
%>
```

### XML Format in (strResponse)

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Data>
  <Row OrderId="1" DeliveredTimestamp="6/25/2015 9:27:00 AM" RouteSegment="1" TerminalId="71" Customer="CONSTRUCTION" ProductId="SOU85" Gross="189.7" ManifestId="qw" />
  <Row OrderId="2" DeliveredTimestamp="6/25/2015 10:55:00 AM" RouteSegment="1" TerminalId="71" Customer="DONALD" ProductId="12" Gross="197.7" ManifestId="qw3" />
  <Row OrderId="3" DeliveredTimestamp="6/25/2015 6:46:00 AM" RouteSegment="1" TerminalId="71" Customer="MRS GERALD" ProductId="12" Gross="200" ManifestId="nbvn3" />
</Data>
```

I am getting the XML response back from the COM method but I don't know how to bind this XML string to the JQGrid. What am I doing wrong here ? Highly appreciate any input...

Comment: Could you post a sample of what the XML looks like?  Off the top of my head, I don't see a Response.Write in your ASP code, which you would need if you're going to return something for the client-side code to use.  Also, I don't see where the ASP code is being called from the client-side code.  Is there anything you didn't post?  Another question - is this all in a single ASP file? If so, can you show where the <% %> tags are?

Comment: Hi, Please see my update. Yes everything is in the single .ASP file which has VB script, Java script and tons of html/COM garbage in it.

Comment: **Which fork of jqGrid and in which version you use? Which version of jQuery you use? Can you verify that `strResponse` have string type (`typeof strResponse === "string"`)? You should change `name:'Manifest ID'` to some other name without space, `name:'ManifestID'` for example.** It would be good to remove all `index` properties and to use attribute names as column names (like `name: "TerminalId"`). Additionally it would be good to add `loadonce: true, gridview: true, autoencode: true` options, but first of all the grid should be filled with data read from XML.